# proto.teacher.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one TeacherReport -- it returned 2

Tags: django, django-models

i'm trying to fetch data from a django model and then store it into another django model but i'm getting this error, can anyone tell how to resolve it. i'm uploading the code with it.

```
lt, created = TeacherReport.objects.get_or_create(
Teacher_ID=teacher[i],
)
if not created:
   lt.Teacher_Name = tname[i]
   lt.save()
```

this is how this model looks like

```
class TeacherReport(models.Model):
    Report_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False, auto_created=True)
    Teacher_ID = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    Teacher_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: You have multiple TeacherReport saved in database with same Teacher_ID, show us your model

Comment: is it because of the name or the data inside of it?